# Installing Spark MLLib on Mac OS X

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to install MLLib on Mac OS X. On linux I just had to installed gfortran by following this post ([Apache Spark -- MlLib -- Collaborative filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758314/apache-spark-mllib-collaborative-filtering)). I have gfortran installed on my Mac. However, when I run:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.classification import SVMWithSGD
data = [
    LabeledPoint(0.0, [0.0]),
    LabeledPoint(1.0, [1.0]),
    LabeledPoint(1.0, [2.0]),
    LabeledPoint(1.0, [3.0])
]

svm = SVMWithSGD.train(sc.parallelize(data))
```

I am getting:

```
14/10/17 10:24:56 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
14/10/17 10:24:56 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

I am not sure what steps to follow to install successfully MLLib on my Mac. I am running Mac OS 10.9 with Spark 1.1.0 (pre-built).

Comment: This is just a warning does the job actually fail. The BLAS library is optional

Comment: @aaronman So, is it much more than a warning?

Comment: I believe that it is just a warning that the faster native library cannot be loaded for breeze, and that it falls back onto the JVM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[Installing Apache Spark](http://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/how-to-install-spark-on-mac-os/) should implicitly install MLlib. Try installing Homebrew, xcode-select, java, scala and spark. Refer the link mentioned for a step-by-step process.

Answer (score 0):

MLLib is part of Apache Spark, you do not need to install it separately.

The error message warns you that it cannot find a local implementation of `BLAS` and is falling back on [F2J](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/f2j/). The reason for this is most likely a spark installation via `brew` or tar.gz from [spark.apache.org](https://spark.apache.org/)

Both distributions are missing a compile flag to use veclib.

To fix this you can either supply a dependency (`com.github.fommil.netlib:all:1.1.2`) or compile spark from sources with `-Pnetlib-lgpl` (see [Failed to load implementation NativeSystemBLAS HiBench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064099/failed-to-load-implementation-nativesystemblas-hibench/49811375#49811375) for a basic howto or read https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html for more details)

Answer (score 0):

I followed this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/installing-scala-and-apache-spark-on-mac-os-837ae57d283f

1. install [brew](https://brew.sh)
2. `xcode-select --install`
3. `brew cask install java`
4. `brew install scala`
5. `brew install apache-spark`

you now have spark . To run a Scala shell

```
spark-shell
```

To run python shell

```
pyspark
```

To run a Scala file it must have a main method. Do

```
spark-submit file.scala
```