# Failed to load implementation NativeSystemBLAS HiBench

Tags: apache-spark

I am running HiBench Bayes and kmean applications, however, I am getting warning

```
17/09/05 09:54:54 WARN netlib.BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
17/09/05 09:54:54 WARN netlib.BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

Can you please give me any idea how to resolve this issue.
I have tried to resolve this issue by following the solution provided on

1. http://www.spark.tc/blas-libraries-in-mllib/
2. https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java#linux

Appreciate your help.
Regards,

Answer (score 12):

As per [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#dependencies). You need to include com.github.fommil.netlib:all:1.1.2 as a dependency or build spark yourself with `-Pnetlib-lgpl.` Building spark is straightforward:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/spark.git   
cd /path/to/spark
git checkout tags/v2.3.0
build/mvn -DskipTests -Pnetlib-lgpl clean package
```

Make sure you have the necessary libs on your system, i.e. check [here](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java#linux) to see how to install them for your OS.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as described in the original question, two BLAS errors. I read your answer and the linked websites several times, but I'm still completely puzzeled how to solve this. It is not clear to me what exactly I need to install and what I need to add to the PATH. Could you maybe elaborate a little? Thanks!