# Pyspark on Windows: WARN Failed to load NativeSystemBLAS and NativeRefBLAS

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lapack, blas

I am a newbie in Spark . I installed Spark 2.3.0 in Windows 10 in order to use PySpark.
I wrote a code using Pyspark and then when I run it , it gives me the following warnings:

```
WARN  BLAS:61 - Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
WARN  BLAS:61 - Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

I searched on the net and found some solutions but the steps are not clear for me and mostly they are for Ubuntu not Windows..

I think the solution is to install BLAS and LAPACK , I downloaded binary packages OpenBLAS from here 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/

But I do not know what to do next in order to install them to be used by Spark?

Comment: These are *warnings*, not errors (corrected wording)

Comment: I used PySpark in order to make my code run faster . However when I used it , it takes a very very long time running .. Are these warnings the cause of this ?? If I solved he problem of BLAS , will the code run faster??

Comment: If your data fit into the memory of a single machine, you have *absolutely no reason to use Spark*, and you will certainly not get any performance improvements (the opposite will happen)... Spark (and similar frameworks) are there only for cases where your data don't fit into memory ("big data")

Comment: I have 689 training instances and (5000 to 43000) features ( depending on the model , I have many models to try) .. I think it is a big data.. Normally when I use 5000 features , SVM takes 15 min to finish training .. But if I used SVM from PySpark , it takes very long time ..  What do you think ? is it big data ???

Comment: As I have already implied, the *operational* (i.e. practical) definition of "big data" is "don't fit in the memory of a single machine, hence I have to use a multi-machine cluster and a relevant framework (Hadoop, Spark etc)". Using Spark in a *single* machine is meaningless (beyond toy demonstration cases), and the idea behind Spark is certainly not to accelerate the training of an SVM in a single machine...

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by thoroughly reading the guide at https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/.

Most likely it's one of the following reasons or both:

1. You did not compile Apache spark with `-Pnetlib-lgpl`, or add `com.github.fommil.netlib:all:1.1.2` as dependency. Without it, no external libraries will be used. Building is straight forward, see [Failed to load implementation NativeSystemBLAS HiBench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064099/failed-to-load-implementation-nativesystemblas-hibench/49811375#49811375)
2. Your system does not know where to find the libraries. Make sure that they are on `%PATH%` so netlib can find them.

Again, it makes sense to read the guide at https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/