# Apache Spark - MLlib - Matrix multiplication

Tags: apache-spark, linear-algebra, apache-spark-mllib, jblas

I'm trying to use MLlib for matrix multiplication problem.

I am aware that Spark MLLib uses native libraries, which need to be present on the nodes. (that it does not come with spark installation).

So I already installed libgfortran library on all nodes (I did the same as 
[Apache Spark -- MlLib -- Collaborative filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758314/apache-spark-mllib-collaborative-filtering?answertab=active#tab-top))

But then I still encounter this error when running on a cluster.

```
Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 11, ibm-power-6.dima.tu-berlin.de): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.jblas.NativeBlas.dgemm(CCIIID[DII[DIID[DII)V
    at org.jblas.NativeBlas.dgemm(Native Method)
    at org.jblas.SimpleBlas.gemm(SimpleBlas.java:247)
    .....
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you add the jblas library to the Spark classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

Spark hasn't used `jblas` for a while; as far as I can tell at the moment not since 1.4.0, which came out more than a year ago. The answer you linked to links to documentation of Spark 0.9.0, which is definitely ancient. So the simplest solution seems to be to use a more up to date version of Spark.

If that is not possible, or if you run into a situation where you have to use jblas again: it looks like you are using IBM PowerLinux hardware. Support for this platform [was added to jblas in version 1.2.4](https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas/issues/57), so you would have to make sure you are using at least that version.